# AngularJS Translation Filter

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I'm very new to AngularJS. I'm using a directive for translation of category objects like:

```
{
"id":17,
"order":2,
"published":false,
"createdAt":"2014-12-29T16:22:43.000Z",
"updatedAt":"2014-12-29T16:23:22.000Z",
"CategoryTranslations":[
   {
      "id":13,
      "name":"Fishes",
      "description":"Fishes desc",
      "CategoryId":17,
      "LanguageId":1,
      "Language":{
         "id":1,
         "code":"en_EN",
         "name":"English"
      }
   }
]
 }
```

Filter:

```
app.filter('categoryTranslations', function() {
return function(categories, locale) {
    var translated = [];
    if (typeof categories != 'undefined') {
        for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
            var category = categories[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < category.CategoryTranslations.length; j++) {
                var translation = category.CategoryTranslations[j];
                if (translation.Language.code == locale) {
                    category.defaultTranslation = translation;
                    translated.push(category);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return translated;
};
});
```

I really don't like the code and am looking for a better way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know much about angular.js myself, but I can give some small tips about your code.

**Indentation**

Code, in general, looks ugly without proper indentation.

I recommend that you indent the body of the second parameter passed into `app.filter`.

**Why are you checking with 'undefined'?**

On the line that goes:

```
if (typeof categories != 'undefined') {
```

Why are you comparing with `'undefined'`?

If you want to check is categories was defined, you could just do

```
if (categories) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `angular.isUndefined` and `angular.forEach` to fine tune the code:

```
app.filter('categoryTranslations', function() {
  return function(categories, locale) {
    var translated = [];
    if (!angular.isUndefined(categories)) {
        angular.forEach(categories, function(category) {
            angular.forEach(category.CategoryTranslations, function(translation) {
                if (translation.Language.code == locale) {
                    category.defaultTranslation = translation;
                    translated.push(category);
                    break;
                }
            });
        });
    }
    return translated;
  };
});
```